# Jackson not displaying in Pretty Print format

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I am using below code to convert my Java object into JSON :

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(new SnapshotModule()).setTimeZone(timeZone)
            .enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
            .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
            .disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
            .disable(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE)
            .enable(JsonGenerator.Feature.WRITE_NUMBERS_AS_STRINGS)
            .enable(MapperFeature.SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY);
  String respJson = mapper .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(obj)
```

This is returned to the Spring Controller RequestMapping which is annotated like below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{xxx}/{xxx}/{xxx}/", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
```

When I print this response in logger I can see well prettyprint JSON format along with indentations.
However, when I hit the Rest URL in browser to see the response is seen with \r\n characters instead of actual new lines with indentation like this -

```
[ {\r\n  \"XXX\" : {\r\n    \"XXX\" : \"XXX\",\r\n    \"XXX\" : { },\r\n    \"XXX\" : true\r\n  },\r\n  \"XXX\" : {\r\n    \"XXX\" : \"XXX\",\r\n    \"XXX\" : \"XXX\"\r\n  },\r\n  \"XXX\" : \"XXX\",\r\n  \"XXX\" : \"XXX\",\r\n  \"XXX\" : \"XXX\",\r\n  \"XXX\" : \"XXX\",\r\n  \"XXX\" : \"XXX\",\r\n  \"XXX\" : \"XXX\",\r\n  \"XXX\" : \"XXX\",\r\n  \"XXX\" : \"XXX\"\r\n} ]"
```

Can someone please help on what is wrong with my approach. I even tried using gson library and result is same.
Please note that since the object I am trying to convert to json is dynamic there is no option of using annotations on pojo.

Comment: `\r\n` is the way used by Windows to do a break line. The editor that you use to read log file convert them into new lines.

Comment: agreed but why is broswer not able to show pretty print and instead displaying \r\n as characters. I tried to replace these \r\n characters with "" but that just makes them disappear. The JSON is still not seen as pretty print but in single line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLUTION] -

I could figure out a solution for this which looks to be wierd but it worked out.

I modified the Spring RequestMapping as below :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{xxx}/{xxx}/{xxx}/", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/plain")
```

So now its like my response is a plain text representation of JSON.

I had tried using application/json when I used Spring Web/MVC. But somehow it seems application/json is not working for Spring Boot.

Answer (score -2):

If you just want the json to print pretty in the browser theres plenty of plugins that do that for you. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc?hl=en